# How do you reorder the shipping services for drupal commerce?

Tags: 7, commerce

There doesn't seem to be a weight option. How would one reorder the shipping services for drupal commerce?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a custom hook to reorder services:

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_commerce_shipping_service_info_alter().
 */
function mymodule_commerce_shipping_service_info_alter(&$shipping_services) {
  if (isset($shipping_services['my_flat_rate'])) {
    $shipping_services['my_flat_rate']['weight'] = -10;
  }
}
?>
```

See discussion here: https://drupal.org/node/1537394#comment-7003814

Steps would be create a custom module or add this hook to existing module for your site, set the weight as code above ranging from -10 to 10 and you should be all set till there is a patch or update to overall Shipping module.

Comment: i guess ill just live with it for now. don't want to add more code bloat to the site.